# filing inactive (no business activity) s-corp return 1120s

Tags: united-states, taxes, s-corporation

In 2017 my s-corp had activity and I used an accountant to file the return.

In 2018 I did all the business under my own SSN, and the s-corp had no business activity.

I understand that I still have to file a return for it or face penalties from IRS.

I have filled out the 1120s form, but there is one part of it that I am not sure about. In my 2017 1120s form, my accountant has put "F Total assets: $10k"

I assume that's the business computers and car that I had. The car has been transferred to my own name now. Is it ok if I put 0 for the total assets this year?

Comment: Which state are you in?

Comment: The S-Corp was formed in PA, I am now in FL